# Kendo Grid multiselect checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-grid

I have a Treeview. On selecting the edit of the treenode a kendo grid for Roles will be displayed and few textboxes (where is edit other properties for roles). The kendo grid for roles have checkboxes and Rolenames. My current code is working if I select one checkbox.

What I need is how I get the array of the ids of the roles if I check multiple checkboxes. Tried multiple ways but I am not getting the list of ids when multiple checkboxes are selected. On click edit of the node EditNode is triggered and on click of save the 'click' is trigerred.

Below is my code:

```
function editNode(itemid) {
var editTemplate = kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html());
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
var node = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);

$("<div/>")
    .html(editTemplate({ node: node }))
    .appendTo("body")
    .kendoWindow({
        title: "Node Details",
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            console.log('window opened..');
            editDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    data: function (response) {
                        return JSON.parse(response.d); // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. 
                    },
                    model: {// define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            Id: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                            name: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                            NodeId: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                        }
                    },
                },
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Services/MenuServices.asmx/getroles",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
                        type: "POST", //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for ASMX
                        datatype: "json",
                    },
                }
            });

            rolesGrid = $("#kgrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: editDS,
                height: 150,
                pageable: false,
                sortable: true,
                binding: true,
                columns: [
                       {
                           field: "name",
                           title: "Rolename",
                           headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">Rolename</span>',
                           attributes: {
                               style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                           }
                       },

                    {
                        template: kendo.template("<input type='checkbox' class = 'checkbox' id='chkbx' data-id='#:Id #' />"),
                        attributes: {
                            style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"
                        }
                    },
                ],

            }).data('KendoGrid');
        },

    })
 .on("click", ".k-primary", function (e) {
     var dialog = $(e.currentTarget).closest("[data-role=window]").getKendoWindow();
     var textbox = dialog.element.find(".k-textbox");
     var LinKLabel = $('#LL').val();
     var roles = $(chkbx).data('roleid');
     console.log(PageLocation);
     node.text = undefined;
     node.set("LINK_LABEL", LinKLabel);
     node.set("Roles", roles);
     dialog.close();
     var treenode = treeview.dataSource.get(itemid);
     treenode.set("LINK_LABEL", LinKLabel);
     treenode.set("id", Id);
     treenode.set("roles", roles);
     treenode.LINK_LABEL = LinKLabel;
     treenode.ID = Id;
     treenode.roles = roles;

     var rid = $(chkbx).data('roleid');

     $.ajax({
         url: "/Services/MenuServices.asmx/UpdateTreeDetails",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         type: "POST",
         datatype: "json",
         data: JSON.stringify({ "Json": treenode })
     });
     console.log(JSON.stringify(treenode));
 })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to get those ids in this line:

```
var roles = $(chkbx).data('roleid');
```

Right? What I don't know is the format you want to get that data. With the following code you can get the roles data in an array objects like this `{ id: 1, value: true }`, check it out:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
    ids = [];

$(grid.tbody).find('input.checkbox').each(function() {
    ids.push({
        id: $(this).data("id"),
        value: $(this).is(":checked")
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/USOso). Anyway you want it, you can change it inside the `each` loop.

**Update:**

To get only the checked checkboxes, change the selector to this:

```
$(grid.tbody).find('input.checkbox:checked')
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/USOso/2)

Comment: Yes exactly instead of that line i want to loop through it so that i get all the list of ids and insert it into treenode. can you tell me where should i add this piece of code .

Comment: @Nethra wherever you like inside the click event, it should work.

Comment: I tried your code but iam getting all the "id" into the ids but not the checked "id"

Comment: @Nethra it should be iterating through all checkboxes. Check if `$(grid.tbody).find('input.checkbox')` returns all your checkboxes.

Comment: Yes it is iterating through all checkboxes

Comment: @Nethra so I can't see the problem.. It has to be all checks inside that array, no metter what, with value true or false. Can you reproduce your problem?

Comment: I want only the checkboxes that are checked not all the checkboxes ids

Comment: thanks for your time and Code. It worked well but the issue i am facing is i have assigned " var roles = ids" and when i debug is shows for roles as [[[object Object],[object Object]] and it has all the properties. When i try to assign var roles = ids.id(Its not showing up)

Comment: Then how do i get only id into ids

Comment: @Nethra why do you want only one id of them all?

Comment: only the array should have id and not any other properties is what i meant